# Call to detach method is not removing entity from persistence context

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

**My environment**

Java 8/Spring Data JPA 2.0.5/JPA 2.1/Eclipse Link 2.6.4/JBoss EAP 7.1

**My scenario**

I have three entities (@Entity): Folder, Configuration and Document.

I have three repositories (@Repository): FolderRepository, ConfigurationRepository and DocumentRepository.

I have one service (@Service): TestService.

Transactionality is only defined in TestService methods.

**My Problem**

If we execute 'test' method, code try to persist a 'Folder' entity in database:

- If entity doesn't exist in database, then is persisted and the call to 'documentRepository.findById' works properly.
- If entity already exists in database, a PersistenceException is thrown. We catch the exception and detach the entity. When we call to 
  'documentRepository.findById' a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is thrown. Why?

I don't understand why this exception in thrown if we have detached the entity. This entity should not be in the persistence context.

**My code**

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService
{
    @Autowired
    private FolderRepository folderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void test(String documentCode)
    {
        List<Configuration> configuration = configurationRepository.findAll();          

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
        Date date = new Date();
        String folderName = dateFormat.format(date)

        Folder folder = new Folder ();          
        folder.setName (folderName);  //Primary key
        folder.setDateCreation (date);

        // We try to persist 'folder' entity using an EntityManager instance. 
        // We don't use 'saveAndFlush' because we don't want a merge happens.
        // If constraint exception is thrown, we detach the 'folder' entity
        try
        {           
            em.persist(folder);
            em.flush();
        }
        catch (PersistenceException e)
        {
            em.detach(folder);
        }

        // Why is a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException thrown here?
        folder = documentRepository.findById (documentCode);

        ............ more code ............
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit of a mess. Why aren't you simply checking if the folder already exists and creating it if not?? Creating a new entity  instance with the same ID as an existing entity is likely to lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: I've updated the code posted.

Comment: As I say, this seems a bit of a mess. Why not ask a question about the problem you are trying to solve rather than your perceived solution?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/276261

Comment: @AlanHay Eduardo encountered a situation where JPA works differently from the way he expects, and would like to know why this is the case. This is a valid question regardless of whether or not his code could be improved upon. I for one am interested in finding out the answer. Even though I would also have written it differently, the fact that JPA works differently than I would have expected here means there is a hole in my understanding of JPA, and I would like to fill it.

Comment: *Eduardo encountered a situation where JPA works differently from the way he expects*.... *the fact that JPA works differently than I would have expected*.... Well what would you expect when constructing a **new instance** with an existing ID? What would you *expect* the JPA provider does when the call to persist is made in this case?

Comment: I would expect the call to persist to work, because the existing folder in the database is not yet in the persistence context. I would then expect the flush to fail with an error, which would be caught by the catch block. I would actually expect the detach to be unnecessary because I think the transaction will be rolled back. Either because of the rollback or because of the detach the persistence context should no longer contain the folder. Then the findById should just work.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. When I try it the findById just gets the record from the database, it even works when I omit the detach. It seems that the transaction is rolled back and the persistence context is cleared when the flush fails.

Comment: Worked without issue for me with Hibernate. Wasn't able to try on EclipseLink. However as I said before it is strange usage of the API and I wouldn't  be depending on this logic.

Comment: @JoostLambregts Thanks for your help. I've observed that if I comment the code that goes after the 'try catch' block, when the method 'test' is finished, an exception is thrown. The message of this exception is "the transaction is rolledback because transaction was set to RollbackOnly". I don't know if this could give you a clue.

Comment: @AlanHay I can't change from EclipseLink to hibernate, but I'm going to test with EclipseLink 2.7.1 instead of EclipseLink 2.6.4.